# What is the smartest way to stretch a layout between two toolbars?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, layout, toolbar

Here is my code. Toolbars have fixed position. How do you achieve stretching middle layout (grid/listview) exactly between them?

Thanks in advance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/top_toolbar">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/id_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_toolbar"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the first `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and add a `android:layout_weight="1"` in the second `RelativeLayout` like so :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/top_toolbar">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/id_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_toolbar"/>
```